# Handle multiple post and retrieve data with angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, asynchronous

I have a problem performing asynchronous calls using AngularJS (I'm using Ionic).
I have stored data in `$localStorage`. Then there is a function which sends all the data to the server. The matter is to stock them back in case of error callback from the http POST request. 
There is my code:

```
var data = $localStorage.prelevement.environement;
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    $http.post("http://localhost:3000/prelevement/environement", data[j]).then(
    function (res){},
    function (err) {
      $localStorage.prelevements.environement.push(data[j]);
    });
  }
```

The point is that when the first callback happens, the for loop is already finished and `j = data.length + 1` so I got an error because `data[j]` is `undefined`.

Is there a way to catch sent datas in my callback function or any idea to handle this?

Comment: have you tried putting a $timeout/setTimeout for each call?

Comment: In my opinion, move the `$http` part into function that accept the value as parameter and use it in the loop. The reason of using function here is to get the benefit of the closure.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap you `$localStorage.prelevement.environement;` in a promise, and then execute the rest of your code. Remember to reference `$q` in your constructor.

```
var dataPromise = $q.when($localStorage.prelevement.environement); // returns a promise

dataPromise.then(function(){ // resolve the promise in the successcallback using then()
  for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/prelevement/environement", data[j]).then(
        function (res){},
        function (err) {
          $localStorage.prelevements.environement.push(data[j]);
        });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, I wrapped it in a anonymous function :

```
var data = $localStorage.prelevement.environement;
for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
    (function(i){
         $http.post("http://localhost:3000/prelevement/environement", data[j]).then(
             function (res){},
             function (err) {
                 $localStorage.prelevements.environement.push(data[j]);
         });
    })(j)
  }
```

Thank you for all your answers ! :)